# Is a non-Jew attending a Jewish school allowed to wear a Tallit during the school morning prayers?

Tags: noachide-laws, tallit-gadol

If no, then would that be sufficient reason to tell Jewish students not to wear a Tallis gadol so that the school don’t “discriminate” against him?

The Rambam clearly says in Hilchot Melachim 10:10 a non-Jew is allowed to take upon himself a mitzva for getting extra reward although he is not commanded, same as women shaking the lulav and the like.

Would that be applicable to the case where two gentile parents agree to enroll their kid in a Jewish school either for religious purposes ( for the sake of being Ben Noach ) or for academics purposes while agreeing to respect the religious dress and grooming regulations and dietary laws while in school?

Comment: Your last paragraph is emphasizing why Jewish schools avoid such a thing, in general. Ultimately, the focus is on providing a good & clear Jewish education to the Jewish students. Placing young children in a mixed environment like this confuses the innocent, naive children, who at that stage would have difficulty comprehending the nuance of the distinction. We are required not to place a stumbling block before the blind.

Comment: Also, practically, what would s Ben Noach student do for half the day or more when the other students are learning Gamarra, Mishna, halacha, etc ?

Comment: Interestingly, this Jewish school doesn’t learn Mishna, Gemara etc. Jewish subjects are taught in a much broad way, from a humanities point of view.

Comment: @yaacovdeane not every community is blessed with a strong number of Jewish children. So in some countries / areas Jewish schools have to accept bnei noach children to make up the numbers.

Comment: @GershomMenachem That’s why shluchim have internet programs for children through Tzivot HaShem. People in isolated areas generally have to seriously think about home schooling. It’s not easy. As an inspiration, it’s important to know that to a large degree, the Rebbe was home schooled. But both the mother and father have to put in the work.

Comment: @GershomMenachem Regarding your last comment about Jewish schools being forced to accept non-Jews to make up enough numbers to finance the school, my comment would be consult with a highly qualified Orthodox posek and Moreh Hora’ah before making such a determination.